# Force prisma order of columns

Tags: prisma

I have a problem where the order of columns in the table is often different from the order in schema.prisma. This issue occurs when I create a table from scratch, not when I add a new column to the end of the table.

How can I enforce the desired column order? Currently, my only idea is to create the table manually using SQL. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do [introspection](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection) to generate the schema file from your database. After introspection, the order of columns in the database and in the schema file should be the same.

So you can create a table in database through SQL and then run `npx prisma db pull` to get this new table information in the schema file.